# Firebase hosting versions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a react JS web app hosted on firebase.

I would like to know how to deploy different versions of the web app.

Example myapp.com/1.0.0 and then another version myapp.com/ -> being the main version

Comment: Just redeploy your app with the new version and firebase will update the hosted site with your new version. If this is not what you meant, then clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting represents your `public` directory exactly as-is. If you want to deploy different "versions" of your app to the same Firebase Hosting site, you'll need to have some kind of process that can put all of the versions you want to deploy into a directory structure and deploy the whole thing.